While genrating Archive build for my react native No Expo project I get error
XCODE Error:

I already tried to delete the DerivedData folder but it did not work.

error: unable to open dependencies file (/Users/codecrewinfotech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/panchal_application-djanommjfdnqgecrzumzfzgdqrol/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/panchal_application/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/panchal_application.build/Release-iphoneos/panchal_application.build/DerivedSources/.d) (in target 'panchal_application' from project 'panchal_application')

I am trying to generate an iOS build so I can test inside Testflight.
